# Which performs better? Primary key with auto increment or Composite key in mysql?

Tags: mysql, primary-key, composite-key

Suppose I want to retrieve data from a large database.So which type of key will give better performance while retrieval?

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to use primary key as it ensures a uniqueness in database, however retrieval of data depends on your requirement and the condition on basis of which you wish to retrieve data